# iOS 15.6 is missing from Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to download iOS 15.6 on my simulator but on the Devices and Simulators window, iOS 15.6 does not show up. It only lists up to 15.5. Why is this happening and how can I download and use iOS 15.6 on my simulator?

Xcode version: 14.0